# How to resolve race condition between ListView layout and IME predictive text

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, race-condition, ime

I have a ListView with EditText views incorporated into the list item views.  When the IME pops up it causes the ListView to resize (calling layout()).  In the course of the ListView.layout() function running its course, it temporarily removes focus from the selected EditText, and then restores focus to the previously selected EditText.

This much is ok, but when I'm using an IME that includes a predictive text component, the IME will change size again (to add room for the predictive text bar).  This causes the EditText to be defocused...which seems to cause the IME to close the predictive text bar...which causes the layout to be repeated again.  Once the layout completes and the EditText is focused again, the IME sees the active text and re-asserts the predictive text bar, causing it to resize again, causing the ListView to do another layout pass, causing the EditText to lose focus again, causing the IME to close its predictive text bar and resize, ad infinitem.

There is a timing component to this, and it varies depending on which IME I'm using, but I've seen it with several different IMEs on several different generations of devices (2.2, 2.3, 4.0, 4.1, phones and tablets).  Sometimes the problem will cycle a few times and work itself out.  Other times it will continue in perpetuity.

**Does anyone have a work-around for this?**

(I regard it as a bug in ListView and/or the IME architecture, but I obviously have to find a solution other than fixing either of those.)

I've tried switching my soft input mode from adjustResize to viewPan, but that runs into a different (but similar) problem.

(When the choreographer first pans the view it moves the ListView (and associated EditText) a little but not enough.  This causes the EditText to lose focus (by the mechanism described above).  When it regains focus the choreographer does not re-attempt to bring it into view--it just leaves it hidden behind the IME.  I've seen this bug discussed in other SO postings.)

Answer (score 0):

By far the best way to handle layout issues involving an input method is to use `adjustResize` along with a subclassed top-level view with a custom implementation of `fitSystemWindows(..)`. Instead of relying on any default code for resizing or panning, your implementation of `fitSystemWindows(..)` can do whatever makes sense for you, and then return `true` to suppress the default handling.